# Cannot run an app from vue-cli on localhost

Tags: vue.js

I installed the Vue-CLI in version 3.7. Run `vue create my-project` and `npm run serve`. Everything was fine and got message

```
App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
```

Though on the `http://localhost:8080/` I got `This site can’t be reached`.

I managed to use `vue init webpack-simple my-project` and then in `./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js` change port number and with the new one it's working but this "trick" doesn't work for `vue create` anyway.

Node version 11.11 and OSX Mojave. There should not be anything that could block the port. I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: What does `netstat -anp tcp | grep 8080` show?

Comment: @MattOestreich `tcp4       0      0  *.8080   *.* LISTEN `

Comment: does it show that while your dev server is on or off?

Comment: @MattOestreich While it's on. When it's off there is no output

Comment: What does the code look like? Does this happen on any other projects? Does it happen across all browsers?

Comment: Code is what CLI has created, I've edit nothing. Yes, the same for all browsers.

Comment: There are a lot of possible resolutions [in this thread that](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2051) you could try.. Try: `npm uninstall -g vue-cli` OR `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli` then run `npm install -g @vue/cli` - some folks were able to resolve it by reinstalling `npm` - there are a lot of different resolutions in that link.

Answer (score 1):

You can override webpack dev host like this:

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    public: 'localhost:8080',
  },
};
```

Terminal output

> App running at:
>
> Local: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
>
> Network: http://localhost:8080/

The answer is from [shenron](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/npm-run-serve-is-not-defaulting-to-localhost/88007).

Answer (score 0):

please run this command in your vue project directory:-

npm run serve

## OR

yarn serve

After run command refresh your browser. this command would be run repeatedly when you get 'This site can’t be reached'.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Remove your Node.js and again install latest version [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. On the installation path choose npm package manager and install
3. Open cmd and enter this:

   ```
   npm install -g @vue/cli
   ```
4. After install vue cli (Previous step) enter to cmd this:

   ```
   vue create name-app
   ```
5. After some minutes (It depends on how fast your internet is) be sure You have the correct installation
6. So enter in cmd  this:

   ```
   npm run serve
   ```
7. Then you should be able to navigate to localhost page `http://localhost:8080`